# Listar vários registros da mesma tabela

Tags: c#

Preciso fazer uma tela listar vários registros de uma mesma tabela sendo um em cada campo dessa tela.

O projeto é web, em ASP.NET MVC e utilizo SQL Server como banco de dados. Não se trata de um CRUD, preciso apenas fazer com que essa tela carregue esses registros nos campos e mostre eles para o usuário.

OBS: essa é a minha primeira pergunta feita aqui, me perdoem caso falte informações.

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida?

Comment: Tipo, é uma tela com vários textbox, certo? E cada textbox desse vai exibir um registro contido em uma tabela. Ao total, a tela tem 45 textbox e cada um deles vai exibir um registro dessa mesma tabela. Preciso saber como faço pra ele carregar todos esses registros ao mesmo tempo nessa tela e exibi-los para o usuário.

Comment: O que você precisa fazer é um CRUD básico? Precisamos de mais detalhes... se o projeto é web ou desktop, qual banco de dados irá utilizar, o máximo de detalhes possíveis sobre o que você precisa fazer. Creio que procurar um tutorial pode te ajudar bastante também.

Comment: Não é um CRUD. é um projeto web utilizando arquitetura asp.net mvc e o banco é SQL server

Comment: AspNet MVC ou WebForms, explique melhor tudo isso na pergunta.

Comment: AspNet MVC, nada de WebForms...

Comment: Jordan coloque essas informações na pergunta por favor

Comment: editei a pergunta